# SVN get file list

Tags: svn, svnkit

I am using java and eclipse, and I want to get **file list from SVN using SVN revision number**.

I have read about **SVNKit** on net but did not find anything that helps to understand how to use SVNKit.

Please guide me to right direction and if possible give step by step from how to use SVNKit to achieving my task. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use svnlook command.

svnlook changed  -r

This will give you the list of all the fles with paths for the mentioned rev no.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. This is the fastest way to list all files and directories in the repository (it also allows to get properties and checksums).

```
    final SVNRepository svnRepository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(url);
    try {
        svnRepository.status(revision, "", SVNDepth.INFINITY, new ISVNReporterBaton() {
                    @Override
                    public void report(ISVNReporter reporter) throws SVNException {
                        reporter.setPath("", null, revision, SVNDepth.INFINITY, true);
                        reporter.finishReport();
                    }
                }, new ISVNEditor() {
                    @Override
                    public void targetRevision(long revision) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void openRoot(long revision) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void deleteEntry(String path, long revision) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void absentDir(String path) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void absentFile(String path) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void addDir(String path, String copyFromPath, long copyFromRevision) throws SVNException {
                        System.out.println("Directory: " + path);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void openDir(String path, long revision) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changeDirProperty(String name, SVNPropertyValue value) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void closeDir() throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void addFile(String path, String copyFromPath, long copyFromRevision) throws SVNException {
                        System.out.println("File: " + path);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void openFile(String path, long revision) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changeFileProperty(String path, String propertyName, SVNPropertyValue propertyValue) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void closeFile(String path, String textChecksum) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public SVNCommitInfo closeEdit() throws SVNException {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void abortEdit() throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void applyTextDelta(String path, String baseChecksum) throws SVNException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public OutputStream textDeltaChunk(String path, SVNDiffWindow diffWindow) throws SVNException {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void textDeltaEnd(String path) throws SVNException {
                    }
                }
        );
    } finally {
        svnRepository.closeSession();
    }
```